# read multiple files with quite similar names c++

Tags: c++-cli, fstream

I am reading a file from current directory

```
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("version1.1.hex");
```

Now a situation is arising that if user updates version then there will be **version1.2.hex** or **version1.3.hex** ..so on in the current directory, but one file at a time will be present. I want to write a code now which will cater this future need of reading different file.

I'm writing this code in C++/CLI.

Comment: Read contents of this directory and look for a filename whose filename part start with "version"

Comment: do you mind using boost?

Comment: @user1903439 _'aha any example ?'_ Look: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]read+directory

Comment: @Nasser. no i dont mind. can u plz give an example thanxs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since file listings are a bit environment-dependant I am not sure if this is helpful to you, 
but here is an example how to achieve your goal under the mircosoft regime.

What is needed is the FindFirstFile / FindNextFile calls which query all files matching the fileSearchKey. Then you can use the cFileName part of `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` as parameter to your open command

```
string fileSearchKey = "version*";

WIN32_FIND_DATAA fd;

bool bFirstRun = true;
bool bFinishedRun = false;
HANDLE h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
while (!bFinishedRun)
{
    if (bFirstRun)
    {
        h = FindFirstFileA(fileSearchKey.c_str(), &fd); 
        bFirstRun = false;
    } else
    {
        if (FindNextFileA(h, &fd) != FALSE) 
        {
            // Abort with error because it has more than one file or decide for the most recent version
        } else
        {
            bFinishedRun = true;
        }
    }

}
// Load file
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open(fd.cFileName);
```

Comment: h should be an handle value. Edited that in.

Comment: thanks alot for the reply. i just tested this code in visual studio but does not work. have u tested it ?

Comment: I just tested it, you need to change the first line to read `string fileSearchKey = "version*"` if not using full path (My code base prefixes a certain path)

Comment: aha thanks ! it works. one more thing. i want to display name of file found on a label how can i do it. i m trying to go ´label.Text = fd.cFileName;´ but this does not work

Comment: any idea regarding this ?

Comment: It might be helpful to use the unicode versions of all Functions. Check πάντα ῥεῖ's link for an example with unicode stuff in it (the first result has one example).

Comment: thanks for the reply. so then ur code will not work for this purpose ?'With ur code i have problem in converting 'CHAR [260]' to 'System::String ^'

Comment: FindFileData.cFileName is CHAR[260]

Comment: from quick googling, try this `String^ str = System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi(IntPtr((fd.cFileName));` but to be honest i have no clue of interop stuff

Answer (score 1):

This code will look in the directory and take the first file, then quit.

***WARNING*** : this will work only on linux

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>


#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char n[20];

    unsigned char isFolder = 0x4;
     unsigned char isFile = 0x8;
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    dir = opendir ("./");
        if (dir != NULL) {

          /* print all the files and directories within directory */
          while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {

            //folder sign
            if(ent->d_type != isFolder && string(ent->d_name).find("version") != string::npos)
            {
                cout <<ent->d_name <<"\n";
                  // Your code
                break;
            }


          }
          closedir (dir);


        } else {
          /* could not open directory */
          perror ("");
          return 0;
        }

        cout << "=========" << endl;

}
```

Comment: i have to use it for windows. do u have a windows example. thanxs

Answer (score 1):

In C++/CLI you should use the .net framework libraries for this. For instance you can use [`Directory::GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx).

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<String^>^dirs = Directory::GetFiles(".", "version1.*.hex");
    Collections::IEnumerator^ myEnum = dirs->GetEnumerator();
    while (myEnum->MoveNext())
    {
        Console::WriteLine(myEnum->Current);
    }
    return 0;
}
```