# C2228: left of '.Text' must have class/struct/union

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am receiving the mentioned error. My code is as follows:

```
String^ result;
result = marshal_as<String^>( fd.cFileName );
label.Text = result; // i have a label on form
```

Any idea. i have a guess that i need to convert String^ to string. if it is, then how can i do that

Comment: Okay, you have a label in the form, but is it *named* `label`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg its a simple label on the form and i want to update its text

Comment: Shouldn't it be `label->Text = result;` instead of `label.Text = result;`?

Comment: I can't stress strongly enough that your FindFirstFile code is incorrectly implemented and massively inappropriate. Use .net framework facilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the symbol to the left of `.` must be a class struct or union. If is none of those. Instead it is a handle to a managed type.

Your code should read

```
label->text = result;
```

Comment: Good. I've finally found the source of that `FindFirstFile` code. I urge you to throw it away. It's absolutely the wrong thing to do. I showed a .net based approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527343/read-multiple-files-with-quite-similar-names-c/24571625#24571625

Comment: thanks a lot David. u really went out of the way to help me. really appreciate it :)

Comment: My final piece of advice is that if you are using C++/CLI, you must tag any questions with that, rather than C++. It's really important to do so, because doing so avoids all the confusion and makes sure that you get .net answers rather than C++ answers.